# Retrieving image from salesforce for iOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, salesforce

I m working on iOS integration with SalesForce. I stuck in following points.
I m using @"SELECT Contact.FirstName FROM Contact" query for getting all member list. Now i want retrieve profile image and company logo for above FirstName person. How can I get these info. One more thing I m using ZKSForce framework.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Swap

There is no images as standard fields for the Contact object so I don't know what you thought you were trying to retrieve.

Using the user record you can retrieve the chatter photo of a particular person, but I am not aware of such a feature on contact unless you have added it as a custom field. If you provide some more information I might be able to help further.

Paul

Comment: It is custom field n got success to retrieve it...Thanks

Answer (score 0):

@ Swap, they have not implemented any function for retrieving image for any user or company logo.
You can see [this](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/index.htm) link for more information.
They are simply returning this information in loginResult.

[image: They are simply returning this information in loginResult.]